# C Program can't open file

Tags: c, file, netbeans

I have program proba2.exe and file text.txt in same folder, when I set command line argument in project properties it can't open file, but when I run program from command prompt it works fine.

```
/* count.c -- using standard I/O */
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h> // ANSI C exit() prototype
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch;         // place to store each character as read
    FILE *fp;       // "file pointer" 
    long count = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
       putc(ch,stdout);  // same as putchar(ch);
       count++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("File %s has %ld characters\n", argv[1], count);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

It works fine running from cmd.exe
[image]
Also work fine( but writes full path for a name of file) when I specify full path in command arguments project properties window
[image]

Comment: Try to add your working directory in running configuration options

Comment: When you run from Netbeans, the working directory is likely c:\users\don\documents\netbeansprojects\proba2 , try to verify that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the working directory of the running program is the same in which the program file is stored when you start it from the explorer. I am not sure where this can be set up in Windows, but I think this is the problem..

Comment: look at picture 2 file text.txt file is in debug directory where is and proba2.exe when I change directory in cmd.exe with cd command I can just type proba2.exe text.txt and program works fine but from project properties I must type full path and program code printf("File %s has %ld characters\n", argv[1], count); writes full path as a name of the file. I guess I placed text.txt file in wrong debug directory or what

Comment: The file is in the correct directory. When you start the program from the cmd shell, the current working directory is the one in which the .exe file is located. Therefore it is sufficient to pass the name of the file text.txt as a command-line parameter. If you start the program in some other way (e.g. from an IDE or from the explorer) it can be that it is started with a different working directory. You can check the current working directory by calling the function: char *getcwd(char *buffer, int size); see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms235450%28v=VS.80%29.aspx